# Can I get a list of events from Facebook without user's authentication?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site written in PHP.
I need to get a list of events from a Facebook page and publish them on a page of the PHP site.

This call works but but it require an access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/mtv/events?access_token=....
```

I want publish the list on the PHP site without requiring an user to login with Facebook.
Is this possible? Is there any way that I can get a permanent token to hardcode in my PHP code?

Comment: Do you own the facebook page?

Comment: Probably not, he wants to fetch MTV events.

Comment: Yes I own the page. MTV is an example from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> offline_access  Enables your
>   application to perform authorized
>   requests on behalf of the user at any
>   time. By default, most access tokens
>   expire after a short time period to
>   ensure applications only make requests
>   on behalf of the user when the are
>   actively using the application. This
>   permission makes the access token
>   returned by our OAuth endpoint
>   long-lived

.

I don't know if this is valid for Graph API.

EDIT:

I think your only chance is to use DOM Parser and parse http://www.facebook.com/MTV?v=app_2344061033, this shouldn't be hard at all.

Comment: Parse the DOM is a good idea but I'm afraid that facebook could change the html in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a public page you should be able to get the events using any access token with offline_access rights.